# How to update / animate a complicated figure in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, animation, plot, matlab-figure

I need to animate a complex figure consisting of a chain of rectangles, forming an arm.
Here is an example of how this arm looks like when not animated :

[image: Static plot]

To animate this figure, I made the following code :

```matlab
function renderFrame(fig, data)
    hold(ax, 'on'); % Need to hold so that new elements of the arm add themselves
    showMembers(fig, data); % Create patches and rotate them to the right angle to create members
    showJoints(fig, data); % Draw circles at the joints betwwen the members. Use the width of rectangle members  
    drawnow;
    hold(ax, 'off'); % Next rendering will replace this one; No need to hold
end

function rotateMember(fig, data, iMember, rotAngle)
    for iAngle = 1:rotAngle
        updateMemberAngle(data, i, 1); % Change thew data so the i-th member rotates by 1
        renderFrame(fig); % Show frame after the data was changed
    end
end

function main()
    fig = figure;
    ax = gca;
    axis(ax, 'equal');
    setAxis(data); % Set axis limits and create axis arrows with totalLength of the arm
    renderFrame(ax, data);
    rotateMember(fig, data, 3, 90); % Rotate 3rd member by 90 degrees
end

main()
```

But the frames of my animation doesn't clear at all. It results in this figure :

[image: Moving plot]

What am I doing wrong ? Is there a way to plot complicated figures with multiple parts and to animate it, by clearing frame ?

I looked into using `newplot` and `nextplot`, but [MATLAB's documentation on the subject](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/newplot.html) is incomplete, as always. I also tried creating graphic objects and then setting the data at each iteration, but it rejects an exception every time the figure is deleted since "graphics objects are deleted".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to clear the axis childrens, except the two axis quivers (arrows).

Here is a code that works properly:

```matlab
function renderFrame(renderAxes, data)

    % CHECK IF THERE ARE MORE GRAPHIC OBJECTS THAN ONLY THE QUIVERS
    if ~(length(renderAxes.Children) == 2)

        % DELETE EVERYTHING EXCEPT THE AXIS QUIVERS THAT WERE RENDERED AT THE BEGINNING
        % MATLAB ADDS NEW GRAPHIC OBJECTS TO THE BEGINNING OF AX.CHILDREN
        delete(renderAxes.Children(1:length(renderAxes.Children)-2))
    end

    showMembers(renderAxes, data); % Create patches and rotate them to the right angle to create members
    showJoints(renderAxes, data); % Draw circles at the joints betwwen the members. Use the width of rectangle members  
    drawnow;
end

function rotateMember(ax, data, iMember, rotAngle)
    for iAngle = 1:rotAngle
        updateMemberAngle(data, i, 1); % Change thew data so the i-th member rotates by 1
        renderFrame(ax, data); % Show frame after the data was changed
    end
end

function main()
    fig = figure;
    ax = gca;
    axis(ax, 'equal');

    % HOLD AXES AT THE BEGINNING OF THE SCRIPT
    hold(ax, 'on');

    setAxis(data); % Set axis limits and create axis arrows with totalLength of the arm
    renderFrame(ax, data);
    rotateMember(ax, data, 3, 90); % Rotate 3rd member by 90 degrees
end

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me as if in your approach, you're not erasing the plot when drawing the next frame. Maybe calling cla() prior to drawing the next frame would make it work? However, this may produce a flickering behavior if the redrawing is done in the wrong order.

I suggest taking a look at [animation techniques in Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/animation-techniques-1.html) to see three different ways to produce animations.

Comment: I tried to use cla, but it removes everything, so I need to set the axis again. Is there a way to remove all the graphic objects that are patches, lines and rectangles, without removing any quivers (arrows) and axis properties ?